# Why "this" is not working?

Tags: javascript, function, this

In java script when we make a new constructor function we use "this.property name". We use "this" to refer the object which currently in use. But in a general function we doesn't use "this" keyword. According to my understanding if we use "this" in function it should point to the current function. However when we used, it was not producing the expected result. Why? Example

> function greet(name){       console.log("Hello " + this.name);
>       }

Output is "Hello" then blank.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: call any function with `new` keyword, and `this` inside the function will refer to a newly constructed object

Comment: where is your code snippet so we can batter to help in right direction @PiyaliGhosh

Comment: I have added my code above. Please look into it. @DivyeshKanzariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because in general function, we are by default referring 'window' object so anything we make it becomes window level object or variable.**

Like,

```
function fun(){
 this.title = "window";
}

fun();
```

or **window.fun();** //both are same. Since we call window.fun, this.title means window.fun.

If you create like this:

var obj = {
}

**Now to make title at obj level, you can do like this:

```
fun.call(obj);
```

Now you can call obj.title.**

Comment: Thanks. I changed my this to window.this. Now it is working fine.

Comment: @Igor, Sorry I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about `this`

In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `new` keyword in javascript an implicit object is created and returned from the function call. Inside of the function `this` refers to the newly created object. Calling a function without `new` does not have the same behavior.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new